# How do I automate testing using nUnit as part of a build process using compiled dll's in .Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, automated-tests, build-automation

I'm using psake, msbuild and nUnit to automate my build and testing of an MVC web app, which will be carried out (kindly), by Jenkins, once I have it working.

My build steps work fine, creating two DLL's in the build\bin dir:

```
 MyWebApplication.dll
 MyWebApplication.Tests.dll
```

I'm using **nunit-console.exe** to run the automated tests as part of the psake build script, pointing it at the newly built **MyWebApplication.Test.dll**. However, the tests fail due to is saying it could not load file or assembly MyWebApplication.dll, despite it being in the same directory as the test dll file.

How do I go about executing tests using nunit in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

I had to compile a debug version of my projects as part of the build script, then run the Nunit console exe against my csproj file for the test project. With this, it executes the tests properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely looking for the application .dll in the workspace root, which is the current directory by default in Jenkins. Try changing the current directory to %WORKSPACE%\build\bin before launching the test.

Comment: Thanks for your assitance. I'm not running the test in jenkins, but from the command line on my workstation. When I have it running on my WS, I will then get it running on Jenkins.

Comment: I see. Since psake is PowerShell based, this likely because Powershell looks in the Powershell install folder by default for any dependencies on loaded assemblies. The only workaround I have discovered for this it to build a version of the project with the tests embedded, eliminating the need for an external dependency.